# MongoDB query using the wrong index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with a schema similar to:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    DatasetID: UUID,
    ID: UUID,
    Model.Footprint: GeoJSONType
    LastUpdateTimeMs: long
}
```

I am issuing a query that looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('redacted').find(
{
    "DatasetID":UUID("redacted"),
    "Model.Footprint" : {
            $geoIntersects : {
                $geometry : {
                    type: "Polygon", 
                    coordinates: redacted
                }
            }
        },   
        "LastUpdateTimeMs" : { $gte: 1 }, 
        "_id": { $gt: ObjectId("redacted")},
})
.sort({ "_id": 1})
.limit(100)
```

And I have the following two indices:

```
{
    "DatasetID" : 1,
    "_id" : 1,
    "LastUpdateTimeMs" : 1,
    "Model.Footprint" : "2dsphere"
}

{
    "DatasetID" : 1,
    "ID" : 1
}
```

My query seems to always use the second index rather than the first, even though the second results in several stages including a sort.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is using the wrong index, and any help would be appreciated.

I've pastebin'ed the output of the explain because of maximum character limits:  https://pastebin.com/LcC3nYCg

[Edit]: Uploaded correct explain message.

Comment: Your explain output says it's using the first index? Which would be the correct index to use because of the sorting on _id. Please confirm which index you think it's using and why.

Comment: Oh damn I pasted the wrong explain, that one was with the hint() in the query ._.  Hold on

Comment: Ok sorry about that, the explain without the hint telling it what to do is now up

Comment: @Dan when using `hint()`, do you see an improved performance of the query? If yes, it's because either index can answer the query, but choosing between them have been known to have some issues since MongoDB doesn't have a complete information about your schema like in relational database and must guess between them (e.g. [SERVER-20616](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20616)). If you need both indexes, then using `hint()` is a viable workaround.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha Yeah I specifically crafted the index for this query, but I need the other one for other queries.  I was afraid that requiring "hint" would be the answer, as I had read that the query index resolver has some trouble once sorting gets involved.  I was just hoping that I missed something simple, but it seems I might just need to rewrite my code to use hints for every query.

Comment: @Dan if that is the case, then unfortunately `hint()` is needed. There is a silver lining though, in that by forcing the issue using `hint()`, you also ensure the index must exist, since `hint()` will error otherwise. This will prevent this query from ever being slow due to the query planner choosing the wrong index, or restoring from backup somehow didn't rebuild the index.